# Inject a string with quotes from PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm facing a problem when trying to inject a string from PHP (using the Laravel framework) into javascript.

The string is like `[{"foo1": bar1}, {"foo2" : bar2}]`.
When I inject this string to javascript using something like `var test = '{{ $var }}'` the `"` are converted to `&quot;`. The javascript string is used in a function later to parse the JSON. This now fails because of the quote-conversion.

It seems that the string is passed into the browser as it should be. But Chrome converts it.

How can I solve this? I've tried PHP's `str_replace()`, `html_entity_decode()`, `json_encode()` and Javascript's `replace()`. Both aren't solving the issue.

Comment: Are you using a template engine ?

Comment: could you not just pass in valid json to begin with?

Comment: You shouldn't get the behaviour you describe unless you have something transforming the variable before it gets inserted. The `{{ }}` syntax suggests some kind of template engine. You'll need to provide more information about what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using blade template in laravel. Could you please try

```
{ $var } instead of {{ $var }}
```

Comment: Awesome! Since I'm using Laravel5 it had to be {!! $var !!}. Thanks, +1 and accepted. Have a nice day :)